# What are the sub divisions of the Tripitaka and what do these areas cover?

Tags: pali-canon

Is it possible to list out the section of the Tripitaka summarizing what areas they cover.

Comment: Do you mean Vinaya, Sutta Pitaka and Abidhamma?

Comment: a good point would be to explore what is more important for lay people inside Tipitaka

Comment: The Pitaka are the highest division. These have further subdivisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I don't know how deep in the *Tipiṭaka's* structure you want the answer, I'll try to give the most in-depth answer. I'll present the ***structure*** in a tree chart and, beneath it, I'll refer to an article with an in-depth analysis of the canon which provides the ***summaries***.

---

## Structure

<sup>*(Click to enlarge)*</sup>

[image]

---

## Summaries

Summaries are provided in "Chapter I: Textual Analysis of the article "[An Analysis of the Pāḷi Canon](https://www.bps.lk/olib/wh/wh217_Webb_Analysis-of-the-Pali-Canon.html)" by *Russell Webb*. It also contains an excellent index of the canon, and an extensive bibliography.

Comment: Can I please get a hi res version of this chart, and a source for who owns/created it? When I click on "enlarge" the chart image goes black.

Comment: try copy it and past it on a word page to have no black background, householder Abhaya Darpana

Comment: https://www.bps.lk/olib/wh/wh217_Webb_Analysis-of-the-Pali-Canon.html

Comment: @AbhayaDarpana I don't know where the image is from but I uploaded a new version of it which has a white instead of a transparent background -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2YXI.png